selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
import time
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
userdatadir = r'C:\Users\adamm\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data'
options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+userdatadir)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = 'https://news.google.com/home?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(50)



So I wanted to open chrome logged in and the program crashes, however chrome opens, doesnt go to the desired url tho. When I remove options it opens chrome, not signed in, but then the program doesn't die.
